# Data Studio API - List all reports for organisation

Tags: looker-studio

Can anyone advise if there's a way to use the https://datastudio.googleapis.com/v1/assets:search?assetTypes=Report api/endpoint to list all Data Studio reports for an organisation. Possibly using a service account? I've created domain wide delegation on my App with permissions to the Data Studio API, but it only lists reports for the access token identity.

Cheers
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone is looking for this, I spoke with the Data Studio product team and there's no option for this atm.

Comment: I am also looking into google data studio apis to list all dashboards metadata.

I am confused by `but it only lists reports for the access token identity. `. the api can return only the dashboards owned by the service account who created the access token?