# How to list all google data studio reports across org

Tags: looker-studio, connector

We are using [google data studio reports](https://datastudio.google.com/gallery). we are trying to list all reports across the org, which is similar to [Data Studio API - List all reports for organisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66046805/data-studio-api-list-all-reports-for-organisation).

There are some possible solutions:

1, Create a org wide service account, and then ask all users to share report to this service account. As a result, we can list all reports by [google data studio API](https://datastudio.googleapis.com/v1/assets:search?assetTypes=Report).

2, Can I set up dataflow job to ingest these reports to GCP hosted bigquery or bigtable?

3, we are doing custom google data studio connector. is is possible to list reports inside this connector?

4, it is possible to add chrome addon to extract the report URL and send to some db?

5, is it possible to setup dataflow job to export [Data Studio audit log](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9690662?hl=en) to some bigquery/bigtables in gcp project?

Any comments on the above solutions? Thanks[4](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/get-started)